# 503 ERROR when starting web app at OPENSHIFT

Tags: java, spring-mvc, openshift, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy Spring MVC app at OpenShift from Eclipse. All is pushing to OpenShift repository successfully. But when i'm opening my web-site it gives me 503 ERROR. I'm using Spring MVC, Hibernate. 
Help pls!
[image]

**My log file**

```
    Jan 30, 2016 1:23:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.p$
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.60.1-8080"]
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1499 ms
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/56acfef17628e1c82e00007c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:14 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [105] milliseconds.
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/56acfef17628e1c82e00007c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war $
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.60.1-8080"]
Jan 30, 2016 1:23:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3612 ms
Jan 30, 2016 1:27:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.60.1-8080"]
Jan 30, 2016 1:27:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 30, 2016 1:27:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.60.1-8080"]
Jan 30, 2016 1:27:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.3.60.1-8080"]
Jan 30, 2016 1:58:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Jan 30, 2016 1:58:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
```

Comment: Check your logs files.

Comment: To check your logs, run `rhc tail app_name` or `rhc ssh app_name` and then look at logs in `app-root/logs/` folder.

Comment: I do not see any errors there. Also I do not use Java or Spring, so I can not help you. May be @fatfantasma?

Comment: @Lucas03, thanx for your answer, i deploy my app with .war file and it works! thanx

Comment: The error is in the log file.  However,  I'm unfamiliar with Java or spring also.

Comment: @fatfantasma, i have deployed not my project but it's .war file in new openshift proj

Comment: @SergShapoval please write up what you did in answer and in 2 days mark it as answered please :) Great you worked it out by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i used: Spring MVC, Hibernate.

I solved this problem in some steps:

1. Creat "empty" application at OpenShift
2. Clone it to local repository
3. DELETE **src** folder and **pom.xml** file from project that you cloned at your local repo from OpenShift
4. Create a **.war** file of project that you need to deploy.
5. Copy this **.war** file to cloned project in **project_name/webapps** folder.
6. After all, commit and push it to OpenShift repo.
7. Open your web app at OpenShift with URL like **yourAppName-yourDomain.rhcloud.com/yourWarFileName**

Will be happy that i will help smbd!